# How should I find the remainder when $ 5^{(5^{31})} $ is divided by $ 17 $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the remainder when $ 5^{(5^{31})} $ is divided by $ 17 $.

So I know that by applying the Fermat's little theorem, we have $ 5^{17-1}=5^{16}\equiv 1\pmod {17} $. But from here, how should I proceed and find the correct answer?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What is $5^{31}\bmod 16$?

Comment: I do not know. How should I calculate $ 5^{31}\pmod {16} $? May you please tell me?

Comment: What is $5^{4}\bmod16$?

Comment: By applying Euler's theorem (If $ a $ and $ n $ are coprime positive integers and $ \varphi(n) $ is Euler's totient function, then $ a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod {n} $, we have $ 5^{\varphi(16)}=5^{8}=(5^{4})^{2}\equiv 1\pmod {16} $. Thus $ 5^{4}\equiv 1\pmod {16} $. Is this correct? If so, then how can this help me to find the correct answer?

Comment: You are correct that $5^4\equiv1\bmod16$, although your reasoning didn’t rule out $-1$   Anyway, $5^{31}=(5^4)^7 5^3$

Comment: So $ 5^{31}=(5^{4})^{7}\cdot 5^{3}\equiv 1^{7}\cdot 125\equiv 125\equiv 13\pmod {16} $? If so, then how should I proceed from here and find the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, $5^{31}\equiv13\bmod16$, so $5^{5^{31}}\equiv5^{13}\bmod17$.   By the way, can you compute $5^4\bmod16$ knowing that $5^2=25\equiv9\bmod16$?

Comment: Since $ 5^{2}=25\equiv 9\pmod {16} $, it follows that $ 5^{4}=(5^{2})^{2}\equiv 9^{2}\pmod {16}\equiv 81\pmod {16}\equiv 1\pmod {16} $.

Comment: Yes. I have figured it out. Thank you for the help, J. W. Tanner and David Clyde.